# T-SQL Sum Values of Like Rows

Tags: sql, select, sum, sql-like

I currently use this select statement in SSRS to report Recent Demand and Days of Inventory to end users.

```
select Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER,
SUM(Issue.SHIPPED_QTY)AS DEMAND_QTY,
Main.QUANTITY_TOTAL_STOCK / SUM(Issue.SHIPPED_QTY) * 122 AS [DOI]

From AGS_DATAMART.dbo.GOODS_ISSUE AS Issue
join AGS_DATAMART.dbo.OPR_MATERIAL_DIM AS MAT on MAT.MATERIAL_NUMBER = Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER
join AGS_DATAMART.dbo.SCE_ECC_MAIN_FINAL_INV_FACT AS MAIN on MAT.MATERIAL_SID = MAIN.MATERIAL_SID
join AGS_DATAMART.dbo.SCE_PLANT_DIM AS PLANT on PLANT.PLANT_SID = MAIN.PLANT_SID 

Where Issue.SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTID
    and Issue.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE > GETDATE() - 122
    and PLANT.PLANT_CODE = @CUSTPLANT
    and MAIN.STORAGE_LOCATION = '0001' 
Group by Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER,Main.QUANTITY_TOTAL_STOCK
```

Pretty Simple.

But is has come to my attention, that they have similar Material Numbers whos values need to be combined.

```
Material    | Qty 
0242-55161W    1
0242-55161     3
```

The two Material Numbers above should be combined and reported as 0242-55161 Qty 4.
How do I combine rows like this? This is just 1 of many queries that will need to be adjusted. Is it possible?

EDIT - The similar material will always be the base number plus the "W", if that matters.

Please note I am brand new to SQL and SSRS, and this is my first time posting here.
Let me know if I need to include any other details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer;

Using just replace, it kept returning 2 unique lines even when using SUM.
I was able to get the desired result using the following. Can you see anything wrong with this method?

```
with Issue_Con AS
(
select replace(Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER,'W','') As [MATERIAL_NUMBER],
Issue.SHIPPED_QTY AS [SHIPPED_QTY]

From AGS_DATAMART.dbo.GOODS_ISSUE AS Issue

Where Issue.SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTSHIP
and Issue.SALES_ORDER_TYPE_CODE = 'ZTPC'    
and Issue.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE > GETDATE() - 122
)

select Issue_Con.MATERIAL_NUMBER,
SUM(Issue_Con.SHIPPED_QTY)AS [DEMAND_QTY],
Main_Con.QUANTITY_TOTAL_STOCK / SUM(Issue_Con.SHIPPED_QTY) * 122 AS [DOI]

From Issue_Con
join Main_Con on Main_Con.MATERIAL_Number = Issue_Con.MATERIAL_Number
Group By Issue_Con.MATERIAL_NUMBER, Main_Con.QUANTITY_TOTAL_STOCK;
```

Comment: Will the difference in the material numbers always be an extra W?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER` in the select and group by with something else. What that something else is depends on your data.

- If it's always 10 digits with anything afterwards ignored, then you can use `substr(Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER, 1, 10)`
- If the extraneous character is always W and there are no Ws in the proper number, then you can use `replace(Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER, 'W', '')`
- If it's anything from the first alphabetic character, then you can use `case when patindex('%[A-Za-z]%', Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER) = 0 then Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER else substr(Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER, 1, patindex('%[A-Za-z]%', Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER)) end`

Answer (score 0):

You could group your data by this expression instead of `MATERIAL_NUMBER`:

```
CASE SUBSTRING(MATERIAL_NUMBER, LEN(MATERIAL_NUMBER), 1)
    WHEN 'W' THEN LEFT(MATERIAL_NUMBER, LEN(MATERIAL_NUMBER) - 1)
    ELSE MATERIAL_NUMBER
END
```

That is, check if the last character is `W`. If it is, return all but the last character, otherwise return the entire value.

To avoid repeating the same expression twice (once in `GROUP BY` and once in `SELECT`) you could use a subselect, for example like this:

```
select Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER_GROUP,
SUM(Issue.SHIPPED_QTY)AS DEMAND_QTY,
Main.QUANTITY_TOTAL_STOCK / SUM(Issue.SHIPPED_QTY) * 122 AS [DOI]

From (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE SUBSTRING(MATERIAL_NUMBER, LEN(MATERIAL_NUMBER), 1)
            WHEN 'W' THEN LEFT(MATERIAL_NUMBER, LEN(MATERIAL_NUMBER) - 1)
            ELSE MATERIAL_NUMBER
        END AS MATERIAL_NUMBER_GROUP
    FROM AGS_DATAMART.dbo.GOODS_ISSUE
) AS Issue
join AGS_DATAMART.dbo.OPR_MATERIAL_DIM AS MAT on MAT.MATERIAL_NUMBER = Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER
join AGS_DATAMART.dbo.SCE_ECC_MAIN_FINAL_INV_FACT AS MAIN on MAT.MATERIAL_SID = MAIN.MATERIAL_SID
join AGS_DATAMART.dbo.SCE_PLANT_DIM AS PLANT on PLANT.PLANT_SID = MAIN.PLANT_SID 

Where Issue.SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTID
    and Issue.ACTUAL_PGI_DATE > GETDATE() - 122
    and PLANT.PLANT_CODE = @CUSTPLANT
    and MAIN.STORAGE_LOCATION = '0001' 
Group by Issue.MATERIAL_NUMBER_GROUP,Main.QUANTITY_TOTAL_STOCK
```